# ag-grid can't pass params.value or params.colDef.field to angular component binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to create a customRenderer on my ag-grid instance.  I'm passing the params into a function which returns the dom element which is an angular component. The bindings for the component come up in the console.logs as undefined though on DOM inspection via chrome devtools shows that there is a string in the field. A console.log of the params.value before it is put into the component binding shows that it does exist.

Table component:

```
var component = {
  controller: function () {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [
        {headerName: "Make", field: "make", cellRenderer: customRendererFunc},
        {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
        {headerName: "Price", field: "price"} 
    ],
      rowData: [
        {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
        {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
        {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ],
      angularCompileRows: true,
    };

    ctrl.$onInit = function () {}

    function customRendererFunc(params) {
      console.log('customRendererFunc', params.value);
      return '<custom-renderer stupid="'+params.value+'"></custom-renderer>'
    }
  },
  template: '<div ag-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 400px;"></div>'
```

}

Angular component:

```
var customRenderer = {
bindings: {
  cellValue: '<',
  column: '<'
},
controller: function () {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.$onInit = function () {};

  ctrl.$postLink = function () {
      console.log('cellRenderer ctrl.cellValue', ctrl.cellValue)
      console.log('cellRenderer ctrl.column', ctrl.column)
    }
  },
  template: '<div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.cellValue"></div>'
}
```

plnkr is here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yfBjMDAKNKgBXdN3rkcN?p=preview

Comment: Messing with the plnkr, I got the values to be passed when I used `stupid: '@',` instead of `stupid: '<',`... However it then threw an error about unsafe values in a safe context

Comment: I'll look into that a bit more, thanks for that though!  I hadn't even thought to mess with the binding function